# Sorting lists as values in a dictionary (analogous to pandas.sort_values)

Tags: python

I have a dictionary, where values are lists (of same size).

```
d = {'Name': ['archer', 'warrior', 'wizard', 'spearman'], 'Range': [10, 2, 10, 3], 'Strength': [4, 6, 8, 5]}
```

How can I sort the lists simultaneously, first based on 'Range' and then based on 'Strength'.
The desired output is:

```
{'Name': ['warrior', 'spearman', 'archer', 'wizard'], 'Range': [2, 3, 10, 10], 'Strength': [6, 5, 4, 8]}
```

In pandas one could do this using `pandas.sort_values`, like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.sort_values(['Range', 'Strength'], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```

However, I want to do it directly in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution:

```
d['Range'], d['Strength'], d['Name'] = map(list,
                                           zip(*sorted(zip(d['Range'], 
                                                           d['Strength'],
                                                           d['Name']))))
```

Here you are basically creating a sequence of tuples (with `zip`)

```
((10, 4, 'archer'), (2, 6, 'warrior'), (10, 8, 'wizard'), (3, 5, 'spearman'))
```

Then you sort it, and finally you can reassign the values back to the dict keys.

Comment: What if I have a large number of dictionary keys? (but I want to sort based only on a few of them, like 'Range' and 'Strength') Is there a more generic way of doing this? Also, it seems that your code sorts also based on 'Name' as the last step, which I don't need. I want to keep the initial order of other keys.